# Dynamically add BoxViews to Grid [Xamarin.Forms]

Tags: c#, ios, xaml, xamarin, xamarin.forms

I am trying to add BoxViews in a Grid format using 3 columns and multiple rows. I have defined the grid using xaml and the behaviour
in the c# file. What should happen is a BoxView should be created for the same number of images with 3 images per column.

Thanks,

XAML

```
<Grid RowSpacing="0" x:Name="scrollBarGrid">
    <Grid.RowDefinitions>
        <RowDefinition Height="50"/>
        <RowDefinition Height="*"/>
    </Grid.RowDefinitions>

    <!--Where the search bar will go-->
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Aqua" Grid.Row="0"/>

        <SearchBar ></SearchBar>    

        <!--Where the images will go-->
    <BoxView BackgroundColor="Gray" Grid.Row="1"/>
    <Grid x:Name="imageGrid" RowSpacing="0" Grid.Row="1">

    </Grid>

</Grid>
```

C#

```
public MainPage()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        int colMaximum = 3;
        int numberOfImages = 15;

        //To add three columns 
        for (int i = 0; i < colMaximum; i++)
        {
            imageGrid.ColumnDefinitions.Add(new ColumnDefinition()
            {
                Width = new GridLength(120, GridUnitType.Absolute)
            });
        }

        //To add an array of rows
        imageGrid.RowDefinitions = new RowDefinitionCollection();

        for (int myCount = 0; myCount <= numberOfImages / colMaximum; myCount++)
        {
            imageGrid.RowDefinitions.Add(new RowDefinition()
            {
                Height = new GridLength(120, GridUnitType.Absolute)
            });

            //To add a new box view for each 
            for (int newcol = 0; newcol <= colMaximum; newcol++)
            {
                for (int newrow = 0; newrow <= numberOfImages / colMaximum; newrow++)
                {
                    imageGrid.Children.Add(new BoxView() { BackgroundColor = Color.Red });
                }
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: what is wrong with your code?  What is it not doing, or doing incorrectly?

Comment: Hi Jason, what I want it to do is print the same amount of boxes as the variable 'numberOfImages' (so 15). I am trying to create an Instagram-like UI where the page will read the amount of images it has to display in a grid format. By any chance, would you know a better way to achieve this, thanks.

Comment: You're telling your requirements, but what is your code actually DOING?  Do you get an error or exception?  Does it print the wrong number of items?  Does it do anything at all?

Comment: I do not get an error, it shows the search bar and the prints only ONE box view on the top left directly underneath the search bar. In other words, it's only printing in the 0,0 region of the grid.

Comment: Thank you @Jason , I then added a margin after to separate the box views. Would you know how to get a scroll view working on the nested grid so I can scroll the box views? Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you add children to a grid, you have to specify the Row and Col, otherwise they will be added at 0,0.

```
  imageGrid.Children.Add(new BoxView() { BackgroundColor = Color.Red }, newrow, newcol);
```